# Does this IF makes any sense in any situation

Tags: java, if-statement

I was going through a partner's code and I found this IF statement.

```
if (((x == 0) && (y == 0)) || y == 0) { 
            do something
        }
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't the first part of the IF redundant?

Comment: Is it a typo? What do x and y represent? Go back to the original requirements

Comment: Yes it is. If `y != 0`, the if will fail. If `y == 0`, the if will pass. So it's equal to `if (y == 0)`. Please note that this kind of questions should be asked on review.stackexchange

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(A+AND+B+)+OR+B

Comment: @DavidBrossard I don't think it's a typo, more like not paying attention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a truth table:

```
╔════════╦════════╦══════════════════════════════════╗
║ x == 0 ║ y == 0 ║ ((x == 0) && (y == 0)) || y == 0 ║
╠════════╬════════╬══════════════════════════════════╣
║      0 ║      0 ║                                0 ║
║      0 ║      1 ║                                1 ║
║      1 ║      0 ║                                0 ║
║      1 ║      1 ║                                1 ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════════════════════════════════╝
```

Clearly, the `x == 0` part is irrelevant, and what you have is equivalent to

```
if (y == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Asking a higher-scored fellow stackoverflower: why can't we flag a question as "should be on codereview"? :o

Comment: @Nathan Because this one doesn't and Code Review would get way too many false migrations.

Comment: Thanks! I was doubting because it is not my code and I dont want to get it wrong, maybe in his think path this made sense. Thanks guys

Comment: @Mast Actually it does, but [this article](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266749/migration-of-code-questions-from-stack-overflow-to-code-review) gives some nice explanations :)

Comment: @Nathan I'm a regular user at CR, so I know a thing or two about their scope. This question would be most unwelcome there for multiple reasons. Please take a look at the [Code Review on-topic help centre](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I'm aware of the question you linked and there are many others like it (like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311348/1014587) and [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/52915)). Long story short: a direct migration path won't happen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in this case it is redundant since none of the conditionals have side effects and if the first part is true, the second part is true.

If, however, there were side effects from the statement, then it is not always the case because of short-circuiting:

```
if( (doX() == 0 && doY() == 0) || doY() == 0 ) { ... }
```

In this scenario, if `doX()` does not return 0, the right side of the `&&` will not be evaluated, so `doY()` will only be executed once. When the `doX()` returns 0 and the first `doY()` does not return 0, `doY()` will be executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it's equivalent to

```
if (y == 0) { 
    //do something
}
```

You can draw up a table of possible assignments. I'm using 1 to represent any integer that isn't 0.

```
x  y  (((x == 0) && (y == 0)) || y == 0)
-  -  ----------------------------------
0  0  True
0  1  False
1  0  True
1  1  False
```

Only when y = 0, does the entire expression evaluate to True, so you may as well refactor it to (y == 0)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the first part is redundant. The second part (after the `||`) will return `true` if `y` is `0`, regardless of `x's` value. This condition could be simplified to

```
if (y == 0) {
    doSomething();
}
```

BTW, it's worth noting that any half-decent IDE would warn you about this redundancy, or, at the very least, could be configured to do so. In case you aren't getting such a warning, it might be a good idea to check your IDE's settings.

Comment: can you give an example of such an IDE?

Comment: @geza I use IntelliJ IDEA, which would most definitely show you a warning for such a piece of code. In the past I've also used Eclipse and NetBeans, and I'm pretty sure they both had such warnings, but it's been a few years, so I may be optimistically projecting and not remembering

Answer (score 0):

The first portion *((x == 0) && (y == 0))* should only return true if both sides are true. The second half is true if *y==0*. This if statement excludes execution when only x==0, but allows y to equal 0 whether or not x equals 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using a `unit test`.

```
boolean isIt(int x, int y) {
 if (((x == 0) && (y == 0)) || y == 0) { 
    return true;
 }
 return false;
}

@Test
public void test1() {
 boolean result = isIt(1, 0);
 assertTrue(result);
}

@Test
public void test1() {
 boolean result = isIt(0, 0);
 assertTrue(result);
}
```

And then, after you run the tests and realize the first part of the `if` is not necessary, you can remove it and run the tests again to check you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You know what? Just draw a truth table of the expresion with and without the first part of the the if expression.

Let's suppose

```
a : x == 0
b : y == 0
c : a && b
d : (a && b) || b
```

So the truth table for a, b, c, and d is shown below.

```
 a | b | c | d |
----------------
 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
----------------
 0 | 1 | 0 | 1
----------------
 1 | 0 | 0 | 0
----------------
 1 | 1 | 1 | 1
```

From the table one could easily judge. I usually just use a reduced expression from a Karnaugh's map. If you guys could do that, then there will be no time wasted in arguing.